$f:\mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$ is a 3 times differentiable and $\max_{x\in\mathbb R}|f'''(x)|\le 1$. Prove that: $f''(x)+\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}f(x)}\ge0 $
I have a problem in Analysis:
Let $f:(-\infty,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a three times differentiable and satisfy:
$$\max_{x\in\mathbb R}|f'''(x)|\le 1$$
Prove that:
$$f''(x)+\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}f(x)}\ge0,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb R$$
Here is my solution:
The Taylor series of $f(y)$ at $y=x$ is $f(y)=f(x) + f'(x)(y-x)+\dfrac{f''(x)(y-x)^2}{2}+\dfrac{f'''(\xi)(y-x)^3}{6}$ with $\xi\in \mathbb R$.
Because $f(x)\ge 0,\forall x\in\mathbb R$ and $\displaystyle\max_{x\in\mathbb R}|f'''(x)|\le 1$, so
$$0\le f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)+\frac{f''(x)(y-x)^2}{2}+\frac{(y-x)^3}{6}$$
At this point, I don't know how to continue solving the problem. Can you help me with it?

The hyp0thesis and the desired conclusion are translation invariant, therefore it suffices to prove the inequality for $x=0$, i.e.
$$ \tag{*}
 f''(0)+\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}f(0)} \ge 0 \, .
$$
If $f(0) = 0$ then $f''(0) \ge 0$ because $f$ has a minimum at $x=0$. So from now on we assume that $f(0) > 0$.
We can also assume that $f'(0) \le 0$, otherwise consider $\tilde f(x) = f(-x)$ instead of $f$. From Taylor's theorem we have for $x > 0$
$$
 f(x) = f(0) + x f'(0) + \frac{x^2}{2}f''(0) + \frac{x^3}{6}f'''(c)
$$
with some $c \in (0, x)$. It follows that
$$
 0 \le f(x) \le f(0) + \frac{x^2}{2}f''(0) + \frac{x^3}{6} \, .
$$
(Remark: This is essentially what you already had, only that we got rid of the first derivative term.)
The last inequality is equivalent to
$$
 f''(0) + \left( \frac{2f(0)}{x^2} + \frac x3 \right)  \ge 0 \, .
$$
Finally we choose $x > 0$ such that the term in parentheses becomes as small as possible. That is $x = \sqrt[3]{12 f(0)}$, and with that value we get exactly the desired estimate $(*)$.
